# Function set works like asynchronous in Next js stores?

Tags: next.js

I faced weird occasion. I wait for a store function but stored data is empty, following is the code

trackingStore.js

```
        getSites: async () => {
            set({ sites: [] })
            set({ isSitesFetching: true });
            const token = useAuthStore.getState().token
            try {
              const { data } = await axios.get<Site[]>(`${apiUrl}/settings/get-sites`, {
                timeout: 90000000,
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              })
              set({ sites: data });
              console.log('in store', data);
            } catch (e) {
              console.log(e)
            } finally {
                set({ isSitesFetching: false });
            }
          },
```

and I wait for it in useEffect in order to use the first site:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await trackingStore.getSites();
            console.log('in useEffect', trackingStore.sites )
            if (trackingStore.sites && trackingStore.sites.length > 0) {
                // using it
            }
        }
    
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

and it prints FIRST
**in store (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]**
and NEXT
**in useEffect []**

Thinking that set could be async, I added await there but nothing changed.

OK, I found a workaround with another function signature:

```
        async getSites() {
          set({ sites: [] })
          set({ isSitesFetching: true });
          const token = useAuthStore.getState().token
          try {
            const { data } = await axios.get<Site[]>(`${apiUrl}/settings/get-sites`, {
              timeout: 90000000,
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              },
            })
            this ? this.sites = data : null; // <<<  it's here
            console.log('in store', data, this?.sites);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
          } finally {
              set({ isSitesFetching: false });
          }
        },
```

and this works as expected (I not checked other set() calls) but I'd like to use provided functions (set) and to understand the thing. Why does it happens?

Comment: Is this related to NestJS, the Node framework, or NextJS, the React framework?

Comment: React framework